# Attach multiple EBS volumes that are different sizes to EC2 instance

Tags: terraform

We are running Terraform 0.11 at the moment. I am seeking a way to have a reusable module where I declare how many non-root EBS volumes are needed along with the sizes of those volumes and they are in turn attached to the EC2 instance. The number of additional EBS volumes could be only 1 or it could be several depending on the business requirement. I have seen that a for each is possible, but that is not available in 0.11. Any thoughts on how this can possibly be done in 0.11 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a set of EBS resources (`aws_ebs_volume`) and EBS attachments (`aws_volume_attachment`) using `count` for those resources in `terraform 0.11`. Which just comes with all the downsides of `count`, e.g. recreating EBS volumes if you change the order in the array of values for your EBS volumes.

As you did not add code examples of what you already tried in your original question, there is no more to show for me. Maybe i was able to point you in the right direction anyway.

We are currently planning a release of such a flexible `ec2-instance` module for our [open source terraform library](https://github.com/mineiros-io) but sadly this will support `terraform 0.12` as the lowest version up to `terraform 0.14`. Once you upgraded terraform feel free to ping us for making a pre-release public.